# revert rejected dialogue/form to show last accepted values on reopen

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm setting up an "options" dialog in a program, where I can change some values and close the dialog with Ok/Cancel to accept of reject my changes. After closing the dialog with cancel and reopening it, i would like the last accepted values to be displayed, however I am know sure how to implement this.

Below is a very simplified version of my code. I chose to instanciate the dialog only once (as opposed to creating a new instance each time I call the dialog), mainly to avoid having to call the `__init__`  and import data from save files each time I open the dialog.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton,\
    QApplication, QTextEdit, QDialog, QDialogButtonBox


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        btn = QPushButton('open text 1', self)
        btn.move(10, 10)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.open_dlg)

        self.txtdlg = TextDialog()

    def open_dlg(self):
        if self.txtdlg.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            print(self.txtdlg.preferences)


class TextDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.preferences = "text here"

        self.resize(200, 150)
        self.textedit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.textedit.resize(200, 100)
        self.textedit.setText(self.preferences)
        btns = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel, self)
        btns.move(20, 100)
        btns.accepted.connect(self.save_and_close)
        btns.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def save_and_close(self):
        self.preferences = self.textedit.toPlainText()
        self.accept()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MW = MainWindow()
    MW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As it is, after clicking Cancel the dialog keeps any unsaved changes to its widgets if I reopen it. My fist idea was to connect the cancel button to a close_without_saving method that updates the dialog to the last saved values before closing, but the displayed values will not be up to date if `preferences` is changed for some reason while the dialog is invisible. Can I run some code when i call `exec_` ? Or is the logic behind my implementation wrong somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a method that sets the values of the dialog to the default values:

```
# ...
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # ...

    def open_dlg(self):
        self.txtdlg.reset()
        if self.txtdlg.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            print(self.txtdlg.preferences)


class TextDialog(QDialog):
    # ...

    def reset(self):
        self.preferences = "text here"
        self.textedit.setText(self.preferences)

    def save_and_close(self):
        self.preferences = self.textedit.toPlainText()
        self.accept()
# ...
```